# htaccess show shorten url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to shorten a long url to a shorter nice looking url
like

www.dom.com/trol to http://www.newdom.com/blog.php?type=user&user=trol

It works fine. But it the browser it shows the long url. How can I show the short url in the browser addres field?

I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dom\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdom.com/blog.php?type=user&user=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `http://www.newdom.com` part of your rule's target implicitly makes the rewrite engine redirect the browser. This means the URL at the top of the browser's window will change. If you want to redirect to a new domain, make sure to do it *without doing a rewrite*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dom\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdom.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That will redirect `http://www.dom.com/trol` to `http://www.newdom.com/trol`, and that's what's going to be shown in the browser's address bar. Then, on the `newdom.com` document root, you do the rewrite internally:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog.php?type=user&user=$1 [L]
```

No `http://www.newdom.com`, no redirect, no changing the browser's address bar.

Comment: @zerkms If the hostname is the same as the current host, [it's stripped off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), thus no redirect: "**If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see the [R] flag below.**"

Comment: Both domains are using the same server and dir. Using the same .htaccess file. It's still showing the long url

Comment: @KimWowBoom then just put both of the rules in the same htaccess file, just make sure the redirect one (the first) is **before** the one that internally rewrites.

Comment: copied your code exactly. Still showing the long url. It's doing the same as my code exept that first the domainname is rewritten. And than the rest.

Comment: @KimWowBoom do you have other rules besides these? (Forgot to include a `L` in the second rule)

Comment: Yes I had. Just removed all other information on .htaccess. It now justs redirects dom.com/trol to newdom.com/trol and than gives a 404 error. (ofcourse cause newdom.com/trol doesn't exist)

Comment: SOLVED both domains were pointing to the same server. But the second domain was pointing to a directory of the first domain. So I had to use the .htaccess in that directory. Damn! time to sleep. 3 AM, but solved. Thank you so much. Your code helped

Comment: just to learn !-f means 'If the file in the REQUEST_FILENAME does not exist' and !-d means 'If the dir in the REQUEST_FILENAME does not exist'?

Comment: @KimWowBoom Yes, the `!-d` and `!-f` checks are to make sure stuff like `blog.php` doesn't get rewritten (causing an infinite loop).